# 5 letters "word" randomly generated

Tags: r, random

I would like to create a vector of 10 "words" made of 5 characters that have been randomly generated. e.g c("ASDT","WUIW"...)

At the moment I am using the following script but surely there should be a much better way of doing this

```
result = list()
for (i in 1:10){
result[i]<-paste(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace=TRUE),collapse="")
}
result<-paste(t(result))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would sample once and turn the result into a data.frame, which can be passed to `paste0`:

```
set.seed(42)
do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE), ncol = 5)))
#[1] "XLXTJ" "YSDVL" "HYZKA" "VGYRZ" "QMCAL" "NYNVY" "TZKAX" "DDXFQ" "RMLXZ" "SOVPQ"
```

Comment: I have to say that I find this solution too obscure (aka. “clever”, which is *not* generally a good thing in programming), and thus inferior to the obvious solution OP posted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What OP posted is the obvious solution in many languages, but not in R.

Comment: @Roland Well clearly I think that *my* code is the obvious solution, and  I eschew explicit loops. But I find it hard to argue that your solution is more obvious, even in R, and the solution with loops is essentially just doing what the `replicate` solution does.

Comment: This is my minor variation, as a two-liner.  `m <- matrix(sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE), ncol = 5); apply(m,1,paste0,collapse="")`  or you could use `%>%`

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think so, as I'm pretty sure Roland was trying to vectorize his solution...

Answer (score 6):

There’s nothing fundamentally wrong with your code, except maybe for the fact that it’s using a loop.

The only better way is to replace the loop with a list application function (in this case: `replicate`):

```
replicate(10, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = ''))
```

Comment: `sapply` is a `for` loop which is the source code of `replicate`

Comment: @David Again, I can’t see a loop in my code. How it’s implemented isn’t really relevant. What’s implemented is the code *I* have to write.

Comment: Loops like this are optimized and are meant to run faster, that's why they are available to us anyway. A simple for loop is slower than the standard R functions.

Comment: @naltipar You are mistaken. A `for` loop is not slower than `replicate`, provided you pre-allocate your result object, which the OP did not do.

Comment: (+one) since `replicate` will often be sufficiently fast and is clearer to read.

Comment: @Roland I'll trust you on that, but still, isn't R code meant to be compact and easier to read, by avoiding explicit loops?

Comment: @naltipar Well, yes. The point is that `for` loops can be an appropriate solution and are as fast as `*apply` functions.

Comment: So if you made a function that has a for loop in it and you then call that function, would you argue that there is no for loop and that it's irrelevant how this function is implemented? Because that's what you are doing now. The post is slightly misguiding, to say the least.

Comment: @naltipar If that function were in *library* code, yes, of course. To reiterate: what counts is the code *I* have to write, not the code I’m calling. This is known as “[abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science))” and it’s an absolutely crucial concept in programming. Without it we couldn’t write high-level code – all code would by definition be low-level. And no, there is absolutely nothing misguided in my post. It follows directly from first principles.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK, accepted. (By the way I'm in no means trying to lower the post's value, I have upvoted it anyway, I'm just clarifying on what the other users been trying to say).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)
stri_rand_strings(10, 5, '[A-Z]')
#[1] "GJOXF" "XYRQB" "FERJU" "MSZJU" "YFQDG" "KAJWI" "MPMEV" "RUCSK" "VQUON"
#[10] "UAMTS"
```

Answer (score 4):

I would create a custom function such as this one which will accept the size of a word and the number of words you want in return

```
WordsGen  <- function(n, size){
  substring(paste(sample(LETTERS, n * size, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""),
             seq(1, (n - 1)*size + 1, size), seq(size, n * size, size))
}

set.seed(1)
WordsGen(10, 5)
## [1] "GJOXF" "XYRQB" "FERJU" "MSZJU" "YFQDG" "KAJWI" "MPMEV" "RUCSK" "VQUON" "UAMTS"
```